# Inserting multiple values into a B+tree at once

Tags: algorithm

Insert into a b+tree is **O(log n)** for one element, and so **O(m log n)** for m elements. Is it possible to do better than this? For example, by making the assumption that most elements to be inserted will be mostly contiguous in the result (and pre-sorting them), is there a way to reduce it to something like **O(m log m + log n)**?

Answer (score 0):

Even if this is possible, don't forget that you need a pretty large tree (n) for 
**O(m log n)** to make a significant difference vs **O( m log m )**, especially if you have a larger constant in the latter case.
Suppose your tree has a billion (10^9) nodes and both constants are 1, then its **9*m** operations vs **m log m** operations.

Comment: Good point. However, since b+tree node accesses generally involve disk seeks, the constant attached to the **log n** will likely be very large (much larger than the one on the **m log m**, even though the latter is asymptotically greater).